# Typescript How to cast a type of a string as a name

Tags: typescript, casting

We have an endpoint that returns from a API, where the types are dynamic depending on what the response is.

How would I return the type of the call to make and import that type into the file.

What I am trying to achieve:

```
import * as ResponseTypes from './types'

export const request = async ({
  APIURL,
  apiType
}: RequestObj) => {

return await fetch(`${APIURL}/`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // Below we need to 
        return Promise.resolve(Response as ResponseTypes[apiType]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Request Fetch Catch Error', error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
}

// Example Call
const userData = await request('..api.com/user', 'UserType')
// This userData would have the response type based on the dynamic string passed through
const email = userData.email
```

So the imported `ResponseTypes` file would have all the API response types in there.
I just can't work out how to cast that type against the response so the type for that specific response are passed back in the response.

How would I type cast this in typescript?

thanks in advance :D

Comment: If the existing answer doesn't suffice, please provide a self-contained [mre] that can be pasted into other people's IDEs and demonstrate your issue, without depending on third-party or private type definitions.  That will make it easier for others to get to work on a solution.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add an interface and use generic types:

```
import * as ResponseTypes from './types';
interface RequestObj<T extends keyof ResponseTypes> {
  APIURL: string;
  apiType: T;
}
export const request = async <T extends keyof ResponseTypes>({
  APIURL,
  apiType
}: RequestObj<T>) => {
  return await fetch(`${APIURL}/`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return Promise.resolve(responseJson as ResponseTypes[T]);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Request Fetch Catch Error', error);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
};

const userData = await request<'UserType'>({ APIURL: '..api.com/user', apiType: 'UserType' });
const email = userData.email;
```